# Kubernetes-Ingress Server-Snippet 503 for mobile user agent

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to create a server-snippet, that will return a 503 for mobile user. I am doing that, by checking the user agent.
The problem:
Server-Snippet is not returning 503 in case of mobile user agent.
All over, the 503 is returned when the user agent is NOT a mobile devide. Mobile itself, sends a 200.
I cannot understand what is done by the Ingress. It seems, as the server-snipper code is somehow parsing it "in a hard-coded way".
Maybe someone got similar issues. If someone might give a hint on such server-snippers, it would be nice.
Thanks

I tried several server-snippets. Please check code below.

1. Try This is a official code snipper from github.

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:    set $agentflag 0;
>
> if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile|ios|android)" ){
>       set $agentflag 1;   }
>
> if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
>       return 503;   }

As json:

```
"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet": "| set $agentflag 0; if ($http_user_agent ~* \"(Mobile|ios|android)\" ) { set $agentflag 1; } if ( $agentflag = 1 ) { return 503;}"
```

---

2. Try

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: 
>         if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile|ios|android)" ){
>           return 503;
>         }

As json:

```
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet": "    if ($http_user_agent ~* (Mobile|ios|android) ) {\n      return 503; }"
```

Answer (score 3):

A short working solution is

```
   annotations: 
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private-nginx 
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true" 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: | 
      if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ) { 
        return 503; 
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a few things are syntactically incorrect. space before the if condition.

Refer this snippet

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  set $agentflag 0;

  if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){
    set $agentflag 1;
  } 

  if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
    return 503;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But that does not fit the problem

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private-nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){
        set $agentflag 1;
      } 

      if ( $agentflag != 1 ) {
        return 503;
      }
  name: keycloak-admin-private-alb-2
  namespace: dev

Comment: still getting 503 ?

Comment: the strange thing is, I am getting 503 for a NON-Mobile device. The mobile user agent is always returning 200. Independent what I am doing.
Even (as json)
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile|ios|android)" ){ return 503; }
is sending 503 for a non-mobile device. But it should be send for a mobile device.

Comment: can you please try again i have updated the annotation.now i have also tested it's working for me.

Comment: @Olli i have changed last `if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
    return 503;
  }` condition.

Comment: @Olli if that works can you please update the post.

Comment: always same result. I am wondering, if the $agentflag = 1 is the correct statement. I will try with if ($agentflag), should also become true

Comment: you can also try that but try with removing other annotation no extra annotation and use these two it's working for me.

Comment: thanks for the support. But eben the shortest code is not really working.
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet": "    if ($http_user_agent ~* (android) ) {\n      return 503; }"

I guess the problem is, that we are using the kubernetes.io Ingress in a IBM Kubernetes.
Somehow, the server-snippet is not processed completely.

As a workaround, I will now use keycloak to route the request to a 404.

Comment: i donot think that should be issue. previously also you were using two classes `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private-nginx kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true" kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" ` so make sure not any mistake is there. kubernetes ingress work anywhere it's not related to IBM or AWS.

Comment: yes, using

    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private-nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"

Comment: try using only one class you added two private-nginc and nginc class.

Comment: annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private-nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ) {
        return 503;
      }

Comment: the last commented version is working. And it is much easier.
@Harsh Manvar Thanks for your hints in this tread.

Comment: @Olli i think it's similar i have added while you removed the if condition.

Comment: you can upvote the answer if that helped that is how it's work. thanks a lot.also add your answer as answer and mark it.